# getting selected index id 0 and unable to move the item

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I want to select the index id of datalist my code is

```
 protected void dlst1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       indexId = Convert.ToInt32(dlst1.DataKeys[dlst1.SelectedIndex]);

    }
```

and i am moving the item from left to right based on the selected item index, but i am getting the indexId 0 and its is getting swap reverse, it should move left to right but its moving right to left

```
  protected void btnMoveright_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        List<ArrayList> temp = 1path;
        ArrayList temp2 = temp[indexId];
        temp[indexId] = temp[indexId + 1];
        temp[indexId + 1] = temp2;
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
        {
            ArrayList lst = temp[i];
            tb.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(lst[0]), lst[1].ToString(), lst[2].ToString(), i);

        }
        dlst1.DataSource = tb;
        DataBind();

        path = BaseDAL.GetImg(Ids);
        for (int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
        {
            ArrayList lst = path[i];
            tb.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(lst[0]), lst[1].ToString(), lst[2].ToString(), i);

        }
        dlst2.DataSource = tb;
        DataBind();
    }
```

Please someone help me in this, how to move the item

Comment: Are you binding datalist in pageload function without checking IsPostBack?

Comment: yes but if i am check ispostback then i am unable to upload the image in datalist

Comment: Could you add your pageload function too? Let's look how we can fix it.

Comment: @ Ahmet Kakıcı: nd i don't think its the matter of binding the datalist on pageload, I have some items in datalist i selected one at that time i am getting id, as i am clicking on moveright btn which is out side of datalist indexId is getting 0

Comment: and when i am making the int indexId as static int indexId then i am getting id but showing Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index in line ArrayList temp2 = temp[indexId];

Comment: and when i am making the int indexId as static int indexId then i am getting Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index in line ArrayList temp2 = temp[indexId];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have added only

```
        int c = 0;
        foreach (ArrayList x in temp)
        {
            if (indexId == Convert.ToInt32(x[0]))
            {
                break;
            }
            c++;
        }
        if ((temp.Count - 1) > c)
        {
         // my old code
         // only replaced indexId to c. Now i am able to move the item

        }
```